# Searching a function with the cctype library to find the number of characters that are digits in a range

Tags: c++, count, numbers, range, c-strings

Trying to solve one of the questions I was given by an instructor and I'm having trouble understanding how to call this properly.

I'm given a function that is linked to a test driver and my goal is to use the cstring library to find any numbers in the range of 0-9 in a randomly generated string object with this function.

```
int countDigits(char * const line) {return 0;}
```

So far this is what I have:

```
int countDigits(char * const line)
{

    int i, index;

    index = -1;
    found = false;
    i = 0;
    while (i < *line && !found)
    {
        if (*line > 0 && *line < 9)
            index++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code not great and at the moment only results in an infinite loop and failure, any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several problems with your function.

- you want it to return the number of digits, but it returns 0 in any case
- `found` is never set to anything than false and thus prohibits the while loop from stopping
- also the comparison `i<*line` does not make much sense to me, I guess you want to check for the end of the line. Maybe you would want to look for a null termination "\0" (here again `i` is never set to anything else than 0)
- and, if you want to compare single characters, you should look up the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the characters you are comparing to (the digits 0-9 are not equal to codes 0-9)

Hope that is a start to improve your function.

Comment: IMO, this is nearly the perfect level of detail for such a question--provides guidance about how to write the code, without just providing pre-written code. Well done.

Comment: Yeah my code was a bit disastrous haha but thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I figured it out and got that function doing what it needed to do. Here's what the revised code looks like:

int countDigits(char * const line)
{
    char index = *line;
    int count;

    while (!index)
    {
        if (index > 48 && *line < 57)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a readymade for this called count_if:-

```
count_if(begin, end, [](char c){ return isdigit(c);});
```